# Rails embed youtube videos on secure site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, youtube, ruby-on-rails-3.2, youtube-api

I am using the **youtube_it** gem to load a selection of YouTube videos onto my site, it works fine in development but when deployed to prod I get a mixed content error in the Chrome console because the videos are coming through as HTTP on my **HTTPS** domain.

I can't figure out how to change the **embed_html5** method to remove the protocol.

#### Here's my code

```
@latest_videos = yt_client.videos_by(:user => 'foobar').videos

<% @latest_videos.each do |video| %>
  <%= raw video.embed_html5({width: '312', height: '240', frameborder: '0', fullscreen: true, modestbranding: "1"}) %>
  <h4><%= video.title %></h4>
<% end%>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at [embed_html5](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/kylejginavan/youtube_it/YouTubeIt/Model/Video:embed_html5) method definition you'll see this:

```
# File 'lib/youtube_it/model/video.rb', line 256

def embed_html5(params = {})
  opts = {:class  => params[:class]  || "",
      :id     => params[:id]     || "",
      :width  => params[:width]  || "425",
      :height => params[:height] || "350",
      :protocol => params[:protocol] || "http",
      :frameborder => params[:frameborder] || "0",
      :url_params => params[:url_params] || {},
      :sandbox => params[:sandbox] || false,
      :fullscreen => params[:fullscreen] || false,
      }
    ...
end
```

You must pass into `embed_html5` that `protocol` option having the value `https`, something like this:

```
<%= raw video.embed_html5({protocol: 'https', width: '312', height: '240', frameborder: '0', fullscreen: true, modestbranding: "1"}) %>
```

This should fix it!